# How to get running total in Oracle using SUM and OVER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am using the Sum() Over (Partition by ...Order by ..) function to calculate the running total of a column, but the problem arises whenever there is a repetition (or duplication) of the value. Sum() over seems to group them by the values and puts the sum of all the grouped by values as a moving sum. Which is not what I intend to achieve. Any thoughts or inputs on why it is happening as a group by of duplicate values and how can I achieve the correct running total without doing a cursor loop by the ranks, is deeply appreciated. Below are the details of the test table along with it's data and also attaching a file with the expected results (highlighted column in the attached file is what Oracle Sum() is calculating incorrectly).

```
CREATE TABLE RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1
(
A1 NUMBER(10,0),
A2 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
A2SUBCLASS VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),  
A2CONTRI FLOAT(126), 
DENSERNK NUMBER);

Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2231113','CLASS1',0,1);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2231216','CLASS1',0,1);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2232517','CLASS1',0.0015,2);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2274031','CLASS1',0.0045,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2281035','CLASS1',0.0045,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2309174','CLASS1',0.0045,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2243993','CLASS1',0.0045,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2301871','CLASS1',0.0045,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2229261','CLASS1',0.0045,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2239639','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2229259','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2223745','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2221525','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2116718','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2259505','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2260197','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2286499','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2293773','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2116719','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values     
(22418,'2308288','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2309143','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2302209','CLASS1',0.0085,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2127518','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308292','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2278399','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2204968','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2204969','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2204970','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2229754','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2259507','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2278400','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280023','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'6501265','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'6501364','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'6501503','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308290','CLASS1',0.01,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2262629','CLASS1',0.013,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2301762','CLASS1',0.013,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2309142','CLASS1',0.013,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280969','CLASS1',0.013,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2267828','CLASS1',0.014,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2294583','CLASS1',0.0145,8);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2302508','CLASS1',0.0145,8);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'6501778','CLASS1',0.0155,9);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2285501','CLASS1',0.0185,10);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2267827','CLASS1',0.0185,10);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2211737','CLASS1',0.023,11);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2216684','CLASS1',0.023,11);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2091315','CLASS1',0.033,12);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2305024','CLASS1',0.0395,13);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308194','CLASS2',0,1);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308226','CLASS2',0,1);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308227','CLASS2',0,1);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2234249','CLASS2',0.0015,2);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308192','CLASS2',0.0015,2);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'6501630','CLASS2',0.0015,2);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2251641','CLASS2',0.0015,2);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2245418','CLASS2',0.0015,2);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2286618','CLASS2',0.0055,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2244631','CLASS2',0.0055,3);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2158617','CLASS2',0.006,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2256762','CLASS2',0.006,4);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2276442','CLASS2',0.007,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2302212','CLASS2',0.007,5);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280881','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2234248','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2259247','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2267339','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2273637','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2273646','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280779','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280882','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280924','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308132','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308134','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308193','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308235','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2265174','CLASS2',0.01,6);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2286617','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
 Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2216868','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2221963','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2286614','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2259004','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2245416','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2245417','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2280925','CLASS2',0.0115,7);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2243903','CLASS2',0.0125,8);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2251873','CLASS2',0.014,9);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2308234','CLASS2',0.0155,10);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2216702','CLASS2',0.017,11);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2302378','CLASS2',0.0185,12);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2264704','CLASS2',0.0225,13);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2273645','CLASS2',0.027,14);
Insert into RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1 (A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,A2CONTRI,DENSERNK) values 
(22418,'2273217','CLASS3',0,1);
```

The query I am using the calculate my running total is as below -

```
SELECT A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,DENSERNK,A2CONTRI,
SUM(A2CONTRI) OVER (PARTITION BY A1,A2SUBCLASS,DENSERNK ORDER BY A2CONTRI 
asc) AS RUNTOTA2CONTRI
FROM RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1
ORDER BY A2SUBCLASS ASC;
```

[image]

[In response to Hogan's questions and his query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k114d.jpg)

Comment: How are you ordering this answer?

Comment: I don't think you understand what SUM does -- it is the total of the partition not a running sum.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am ordering by A2Contri field which is the field to be used for deriving the running total. I don't disagree with you and take it on me that I am likely not using the Sum function the right way to derive the running total, but the intention is to create the running total by the Subclass, hence I was using the partition clause. The Denserank will be reset to a 1 for a new subclass (field A2Subclass) and thus the running total will be starting new for every new A2Subclass value.

Comment: @Hogan - that is wrong. The analytic SUM does EXACTLY what the OP thinks it does. You get the total of the partition only if you omit the ORDER BY clause in the analytic clause of the function (which is valid, but it is only one of the options).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default analytic functions use a RANGE windowing directive (see below - the default is the first version). What you are looking for is a ROWS directive (see below), which is not the default so you must include it explicitly.

The RANGE windowing clause (default) does exactly what you noticed: it treats all "tied" rows as "included in the sum".

ADDED: Link to documentation   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97640

```
with test_data ( x ) as (
       select  10 from dual union all
       select  20 from dual union all
       select  30 from dual union all
       select  30 from dual union all
       select  30 from dual union all
       select 100 from dual
     )
select x
     , sum(x) over (order by x range between unbounded preceding and current row) range_sum
     , sum(x) over (order by x rows  between unbounded preceding and current row) rows_sum
from   test_data
order by x;

         X  RANGE_SUM   ROWS_SUM
---------- ---------- ----------
        10         10         10
        20         30         30
        30        120         60
        30        120         90
        30        120        120
       100        220        220
```

Comment: very interesting!!! New learning and Thank You!! let me play around with the Rows Between function a bit and see what I can come up to this...But again, a Big Thanks to you to passing on the knowledge...as the saints say, live to learn, always!!!

Comment: Got the desired results based on @mathguy's teachings - for reference, this is what I changed to my queries in order to achieve a moving running total based on a specific field. ` SELECT A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,DENSERNK,A2CONTRI,
  SUM(A2CONTRI) OVER (PARTITION BY A2SUBCLASS ORDER BY A2SUBCLASS,DENSERNK ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) RUNNINGTOTBYSUBCLASS
FROM RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1;`
ORDER BY A2SUBCLASS ASC;

Comment: Trick is to use the Rows Between clause with Unbounded preceding and Current Row conditions - as long as we define the window or the partition for the rows between clause to deal with, Sum (over) works like a charm. While reading through the documentation @mathguy provided, it looks like we can also use a value expr condition to the Rows Between clause. I'd be playing around with a few examples to see how that works - This is very interesting and Thanks to mathguy once again for providing us a crucial insight on how Analytical functions work!!

Answer (score 0):

The question is about Oracle and my answer below is based on DB2 OLAP implementation -- which has different defaults.  See @mathguy's answer for the correct Oracle syntax.

If you want a running sum don't use partition by except in the ranges you want the running sum to "span", it will then be ordered by the the order by part, which in this question is not valid or specific enough, it is not clear what ordering you are using -- I took a guess below -- should be close.

```
SELECT A1,A2,A2SUBCLASS,DENSERNK,A2CONTRI,
  SUM(A2CONTRI) OVER (ORDER BY DESNSERNK, A2, A2CONTRI) AS RUNTOTA2CONTRI
FROM RUNNINGTOTAL_TEST1
ORDER BY A2SUBCLASS ASC;
```

Comment: this is not giving me the correct running total too. I intended ordering on the field named as Densernk for all values of A2 having same 
 the A2Subclass. Everytime A2Subclass changes, my Densernk is reset to a 1 and the running total to be calculated as a fresh. I wish I could add a jpeg file in this comment, but I will try to add to the original post. Thanks for your help though!! Much appreciated...

Comment: @Hogan - What do you mean? A running sum WITHIN EACH PARTITION is absolutely valid and is calculated EXACTLY with the analytic SUM function, with PARTITION BY and ORDER BY. The only issue in the OP's code is the windowing clause, which should use ROWS BETWEEN...  (the default is RANGE BETWEEN... which does exactly what the OP reported). I recommend that you delete this answer, since it may mislead people who are not familiar with analytic functions (like yourself).

Comment: @mathguy -- I re-wrote my answer to be correct in the way you point out they may be miss-understood,  but your comments seem slightly disingenuous since you didn't use a partition by in your answer -- which was the point I was making.  In DB2 (which is the platform I can test on) the default is different than you describe and this would work just fine.  I think you should be not suggest people delete their answers... it is.. well... to say it nicely.... impolite.  You have the option to to flag my answer as and see if someone else feels it should be deleted.

Comment: @Hogan - PARTITION BY was never the issue, and I intentionally didn't use it in my reply because it is irrelevant - the only issue had to do with the windowing clause. The part that I wanted you to delete (which was the entire answer when I suggested that) said "if you want a running sum don't use partition by", which is incorrect in any database that implements the SQL Standard; analytic functions weren't invented by Oracle. As to "impolite" - all I want is to keep wrong answers off this site, especially from highly-ranked posters who **will** be believed otherwise.

Comment: And the DB2 documentation says: **If window-order-clause is specified, but window-aggregation-group-clause is not specified, the window aggregation group consists of all rows that precede a given row of the partition of the given row or all rows that are peers of the given row in the window ordering of the window partition that is defined by the window-order-clause.**  Which is EXACTLY THE SAME as in Oracle (not surprisingly - this is SQL STANDARD). https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.html

Comment: @mathguy - that quote is exactly what I said -- don't specify the aggregation group then it is a running total  (hint: "all rows that precede a given row" is running total) I believed db2 and Oracle followed the standard thus in my original post -- which is now clearly correct - but I believed you and Bendon saying it didn't work.  So -- since my answer was right can we delete this discussion? I'm not going to delete it -- but you are still welcome to flag it for a moderator if you still think it should be deleted.

Comment: "window aggregation group clause" is not the PARTITION BY clause, it is the RANGE BETWEEN... or ROWS BETWEEN... clause. Your answer was completely wrong. Other than that - flagging for a moderator should only be used when answers are abusive, blatantly commercial, etc.; moderators should not (and I believe do not) have the power to remove answers simply because they are wrong. That is why I asked you, not a moderator. Do as you please.