# Oracle: how to calculate running total

Tags: oracle

Oracle 19.3 on Windows.
Trying to figure out how to show a running total.
Inner table shows unique sku_id and its qty sold.
I am trying to show a running total, but in some instances, when I sold the same number of items, running total is not changing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
select sku_id, sku_qty, sum(sku_qty) over (ORDER BY sku_qty desc) running_total
from (
                -- April sales
                select
                    sku_id
                    ,sum(item_qty) sku_qty
                from ecomm_order_item
                where extract(YEAR from created_date) = 2021
                  and extract(MONTH from created_date) = 4
                group by sku_id
                order by sku_qty desc
)
order by sku_qty desc
```

[image]

Comment: Your `SKU_QTY` column rows are not unique. That's why your window function returns the same sub-total for equal `SKU_QTY` values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get running total in Oracle using SUM and OVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466453/how-to-get-running-total-in-oracle-using-sum-and-over)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ordering by `sku_qty` and if you have two rows with the same `sku_qty` then they will have the same rank in the ordering and the `SUM` will count them both at the same time.

If you want them to be counted separately then you need to give them a unique ordering.

For example, you could add `sku_id` to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
select sku_id,
       sku_qty,
       sum(sku_qty) over (ORDER BY sku_qty desc, sku_id) running_total
from  ...
```

Or, could use `ROWNUM`

```sql
select sku_id,
       sku_qty,
       sum(sku_qty) over (ORDER BY sku_qty desc, ROWNUM) running_total
from  ...
```

Or anything else unique.

---

Or, you could change the windowing clause from the default `RANGE` window to use `ROWS`:

```sql
select sku_id,
       sku_qty,
       sum(sku_qty) over (
         ORDER BY sku_qty desc
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) running_total
from  ...
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5621f4ff1f99ba2f4587e7e1d061e486)*

Comment: Thank you very much. learned something new